# Code object and purpose of co_name attribute

Tags: python, global, internals

Follows by the `python reference manual` we've that

> Code objects represent byte-compiled executable Python code, or
>   bytecode.

and

> Special read-only attributes: co_name gives the function name;

What is the value of `co_name` if the current compiled code doesn't depends on any function (i.e. global module code)?

Comment: Did you try it?  Play around with `compile` function.

Comment: `print compile("a = 10", "<string>", "exec").co_name` - `<module>`

Comment: @BrenBarn I think that we can't take access to an objects of any internal types. Might it possible to recieve an instance of execution frame internal object?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: I don't understand what "take access to an objects of any internal types" means.

Comment: @BrenBarn Is it possible to get an instance of frame object which correponding to a current execution code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> print inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name
<module>
```

Using [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) to get the code object of the current stack frame in interactive mode, we find that the `co_name` is `'<module>'`.